# Как разбить строку на отдельные массивы?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, массивы, qt

Имею вот такой код.

```
QRegExp rx("(\\\n|\\:|\\;)");
QString myString("login@mail.ru;pass\nlogin2@mail.ru;pass2\nlia@dll:pass3");

QStringList myStringList = myString.split(rx);

for (int index = 0; index < myStringList.length(); index++)
{
    std::cout << "[" << index << "] " << 
                 myStringList.at(index).toStdString() << std::endl;
}
```

На выходе получаю вот такое:

```
[0] login@mail.ru
[1] pass
[2] login2@mail.ru
[3] pass2
[4] lia@dll
[5] pass3
```

Задача состоит в том, чтобы получить массив такого вида:

```
[0][1] login@mail.ru
[0][2] pass
[1][1] login2@mail.ru
[1][2] pass2
```

Comment: На C# было бы: `myString.Split('\n').Select(s => s.Split(';'))`.

Comment: @VladD, да, на C# очень просто кодировать, а вот на C++ нужно танцевать на огне =)

Comment: А в желаемом выводе индексация точно правильная?

Comment: @TimofeyBondarev , да, желательно такая. Но смысла особого нет, нужно просто группировать их.

Comment: Очень похоже на недавний [вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420088/Разделение-строки/420121) про разбиение строки на предложения, а предложений на отдельные слова.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может так?

```
QRegExp rx("(\\:|\\;)");
QString str("login@mail.ru;pass\nlogin2@mail.ru;pass2\nlia@dll:pass3");

QList<QStringList> result;
foreach(const QString &lst1, str.split(QLatin1Char('\n')))
   result << lst1.split(rx);
```

В `result` будет:

```
(("login@mail.ru", "pass"), ("login2@mail.ru", "pass2"), ("lia@dll", "pass3"))
```

Comment: Отлично! Работает! Огромное спасибо!